# Any sources that discuss חזרה (review) programs in detail?

Tags: sources-mekorot, torah-study

What sources provide details of in what frequency one should review one's material?

For me, two come to mind.

The Gemara (where?) that a student would review all his learning every 30 days, which Tosfos explains as reviewing the "Chapter Titles".

The 2nd is the Be'er Hagolah:

> באר הגולה, יו"ד א' א', באר הגולה [ח]: "...אמר מהר"ש שקבלה בידו מאחיו
>   הר"ר יונה ז"ל שיש לכל שוחט ושוחט כשמתחיל לשחוט לחזור הלכות שחיטות
>   ובדיקות בכל יום פעם אחת, וכן יעשה שלשים יום, ואח"כ בכל חודש פעם אחת,
>   וכן יעשה שנה תמימה, ואח"כ פעם אח' לכל תקופה, וכן יעשה כל ימי חייו, ואם
>   לא עשה כן שחיטתו פסולה עכ"ל..."

Comment: Somewhere in the introduction to the Shulchan Aruch it says that it is meant to be reviewed every 30 days.

Comment: Possibly related answer (depending on what you're looking for): http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/10870

Comment: Rav Kook wrote in a letter to his brother that reviewing a chapter of _G'mara_ any fewer than 10 times is as good as not having learned it. This letter is _somewhere_ in _Igros Har'iya_.

Answer (score 1):

the Steipler zt'l gave a method for learning/reviewing mishnayot [here](http://dafyomireview.com/article.php?docid=152&seriesid=4). can be applied to other material.

I think it's based on Eruvin 54b see [here](http://dafyomi.co.il/eruvin/points/ev-ps-054.htm) where it says: "the ideal seder of learning"

hence the frequency is four times,etc. then move on until whenever. I once read in a book on Rav Ovadiah Yosef zt'l who was reputed to have a photographic memory, that when he was asked how he merited such memory, he replied something like: "if you learn it very very clearly, then you cannot forget".