# How to properly chazar gemarah?

Tags: torah-study

Do any of the rishonim/acharonim/etc speak about how one should go about properly chazzaring the gemarah that he learns on a daily basis?

Comment: Duplicate of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35602?

Comment: An answer is at http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/10870.

Comment: Not an answer, but it is good to read this book accurately, Chazon Ish loved it, Rashab (Lubavitsh too): [see here](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/21689)

Comment: This is question seems pretty broad. Is it on topic?

Comment: Is there some particular aspect that you are asking about? E.g. "should one prioritize studying old material over new material", "how many times should one review something" "when in the day should one review" "something else"? What exactly is being asked?

Comment: Chazarah. Chazarah. Chazarah. And then? Chazarah!

Comment: @DonielF: Did you happen to be in Rabbi Dovid Newman's shiur?

Comment: @RealTorah No, but our Bekius shiur followed the Veha'arev Na program. I don't live anywhere near New Jersey.

Answer (score 1):

Rav Elyashiv reportedly [said](http://dafyomireview.com/article.php?docid=395) the proper way to review is:

> The primary review which brings benefit is review whereby one learns
>   the matter again anew (od paam mechadash es hainyan). This takes alot
>   of time, though it is quicker than the first time, but it takes time.
>   But the toeles (benefit) is davka (specifically) from reviews like
>   this"

Comment: What does this mean?

Comment: @Yehoshua it means not to review like a parrot but to learn it anew as if you never learned it before

Answer (score 1):

Books:

1) [*The Longer-Shorter Way*](http://www.menuchapublishers.com/browse-jewish-books/jewish-parenting-teaching-books/the-longer-shorter-way.html) by Rabbi Yehoshua Paltiel

2) [*Brain Power*](http://www.israelbookshoppublications.com/store/pc/Brain-Power-p680.htm) by Aharon Yehoshua Pessin

Links:

1) http://www.vhaarevna.com

2) http://www.shaschabura.org/

Gedolim:

3) Rav Yaakov Yisrael Kanievsky said, *"... When you know the sugya well, review it four times, then study further according to this system."* (Karyana D'Igarta, volume I, #11; see also [*Zos Brisi*](http://www.feldheim.com/sefer-zos-brisi.html) by Rabbi Shimon Finkelman